# How to differenciate between static and dynamic methodMissing and avoid StackOverflowError

Tags: groovy

I use methodMissing in a delegate.

What is possible in order to avoid mistake such this:
java.lang.StackOverflowError
just because:

```
def methodMissing(String methodName, args) { 
pritln "did you notice the method name mistake ?"
}
```

I was thinking of between a mechanism to differenciate static / dynamic (i.e. when .call() is called on the closure)

Any pointers ?

Comment: Write a test to make sure the methodMissing method works?

Answer (score 0):

What about this little Groovy script?

```
def methodMissing(String methodName, args) {
   println "in methodMissing"
   if (!methodCalled()) {
      pritln "did you notice the method name mistake ?"
   }
}

def methodCalled(methodName = 'methodMissing') {
   Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace().findAll {it.className == this.class.name}.methodName.contains methodName
}

nothingHere()
```